# Trigger code when alarm from Clock-application starts in Android

Tags: android, notifications, clock, alarm

Is there anyway to trigger some code when the Alarm in the clock-application is executed? I read about the Alarm Manager but its only for creating your own alarms.

I guess you will never be sure if the clock-application exists on the device. But if it does I would like to get notified.

/Br Johannes

Answer (score 6):

**Warning:** You are trying to get a notification about a Clock's state.  This app is not part of official Android SDK: the solution below is not supported (or recommended) by Google and subject to change without notice.

Take a look at the source code od DeskClock (a new name for AlarmClock). Specifically take a look at it's [AndroidManifest.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=blob;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=295dba8e55dff9e1377d318c49f497a3177aa86a;hb=HEAD).

It seems that it receives `com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT`:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
        <action android:name="alarm_killed" />
        <action android:name="cancel_snooze" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Try registering this receiver in your app.

Comment: This is not part of the Android SDK. It is subject to change. Google does not recommend doing what Mr. Knego suggests.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I agree with you. But what OP tries to do is get a notification about a private app. This is bound to be non-supported and subject to change without notice. I edited my post and added a warning.